# Move a div with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the following code `.logo` is hidden by default. I want to display it on scroll, so when it appears I want to move the `<ul>` to the right with some animation (for example sliding to the right). If you see the demo, you can see that when the logo appears or disappears, the `<ul>` changes its position in quite bad way, I want to make it more smooth.

How that can be achieved?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/C0ZR4RK.png" /></div>
    <ul class="list">
        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>dolor sit amet</li>
        <li>consectetur.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    var shrinkHeader = 300;
    $(".logo").hide();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
        if (scroll >= shrinkHeader) {
            $('.header').addClass('shrink');
            $(".logo").fadeIn("slow");
        } else {
            $('.header').removeClass('shrink');
            $(".logo").fadeOut("slow");
        }
    });

    function getCurrentScroll() {
        return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }

});
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/ztdr68aw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `absolute` positioning for your text you want animated. Then just give it the initial position you want and the one it should have once shrunken:

```
            ul {
                list-style: none;
                font-size: 22px;
                position:absolute;
                top:5px;
                left:10px;
                transition:all .3s;
            }

            .shrink ul{
                left:200px;
                top:10px;
            }
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ztdr68aw/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try if this would help you,

http://jsfiddle.net/raaj_obuli/ztdr68aw/1/

```css
.list {

  position: absolute;

  left: 0;

  top: 0;

  transition: all 500ms;

}

.header.shrink .list {

  left: 200px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you. Thanks!

```
 $(function(){
 var shrinkHeader = 300;
    $( ".logo" ).hide();
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
      if ( scroll >= shrinkHeader ) {                                
          $('.header').addClass('shrink');
          $( ".logo" ).show();
        }
        else {
            $('.header').removeClass('shrink');
            $( ".logo" ).hide();
        }
  });

function getCurrentScroll() {
    return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code

```
ul {
            list-style: none;
            font-size: 22px;
            position:absolute;
            top:5px;
            left:10px;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
            -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
            -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
             -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
              transition: all 0.4s ease;
        }

        .shrink ul{
            left:200px;
            top:10px;
        }
```